# MongoDB convert dictionary<Enum,dictionary<int,double>> to bson

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have an attribute like I said in title dictionary<Enum,dictionary<int,double>>. I want to
record it to mongodb but I have a problem with converting to bson.

```
 var jsonDoc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
 var bsonDoc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonDoc);
```

I tried the above code, but this code did not convert the dictionary in the value part.
I need to help about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, long>> MapHeroDict2 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, long>>();
```

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TFCombatMap>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                var customDictionarySerializer =
                    new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, long>>>(
                        dictionaryRepresentation: DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays,
                        keySerializer: new Int32Serializer(BsonType.String),
                        valueSerializer: new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<int, long>>(
                            dictionaryRepresentation: DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays,
                            keySerializer: new Int32Serializer(BsonType.String),
                            valueSerializer: BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<long>()));
                cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.MapHeroDict2).SetSerializer(customDictionarySerializer);
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although your code snippet may solve the OP problem, it is advised to explain what was wrong before and how it will help.